# Saving high-resolution images with plotnine

Tags: python, ggplot2, plotnine

I'm trying to use plotnine to save a high-resolution png image.

With a test dataset, this looks like:

```
from plotnine import *
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame()
df['x'] = np.arange(0,10,0.01)
df['y'] = np.sin(df['x'])

p = ggplot(df, aes(x='x',y='y')) + labs(x='x', y='y') + geom_point(size=0.1)
p.save(filename = 'test3.png', height=5, width=5, units = 'in', dpi=1000)
```

This produces a low-resolution .png file containing my plot, which is not improved when I increase the specified dpi.

I've also tried saving with:

```
ggsave(plot=p, filename='test.png', dpi=1000)
```

and replacing `dpi=1000` with `res=1000`. This produces identical low-resolution png files.

How can I save my plot at the resolution I want?

Edit: This bug is resolved in plotnine version 0.3.0. and the above code works correctly.

Comment: What do you mean by low-resolution? Note that with a dpi of 1000, what you are saying is that I want an image that is printable at 1000 dpi or looks good on hi-res monitor. Beyond some dpi (about 300), you will most likely be creating images specifically for print. Check out https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/36683/how-does-size-work-with-png-8-and-png-24-images.

Comment: The images that are being saved are at around dpi 100, regardless of whether I specify 100, 300, or 2000. I'm looking for about 300 dpi for the final image.

Comment: Update to the latest version of plotnine. You are experiencing a bug that was fixed.

Comment: Resolved, thank you!
I updated plotnine just before encountering this problem. I used:
$ conda update plotnine
Which installed version 0.2.1, and did not see version 0.3.0. Adding conda-forge:
$ conda config --add channels conda-forge
Allowed conda update to see and install the latest version of plotnine, which fixed the bug. I am now seeing beautiful, variable-resolution plots.

Comment: SO considers a question "open" until an answer is either accepted or there's at least one up-voted answer. Since the above worked for you, you could answer your own question, or delete, since the bug is fixed so it's unlikely anyone else will have this question. :-)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Since this still isn't answered and I just got directed here, too...

According to @has2k1 (the author of `plotnine`), this was a bug and is now resolved. [This commit](https://github.com/has2k1/plotnine/commit/833ecf2051a08599b7cd6ae87f7ad55ab03fdb7d) looks like it might be the referenced fix.

To solve the issue, ensure you are using the git version or at least [version 0.3.0](https://github.com/has2k1/plotnine/releases/tag/v0.3.0).

Answer (score 0):

There is also the possibility to save the matplotlib figure

```
import plotnine as pn

fig, plot = (pn.ggplot()
 + ...

 + pn.theme(panel_background=pn.element_blank())
 + pn.theme(axis_title_y=pn.element_blank())
 + pn.theme(axis_ticks_major_y=pn.element_blank())
 + pn.theme(figure_size=(12, 8))
             ).draw(show=False, return_ggplot=True)

fig.savefig('image.png', dpi=300)
```

which worked ok for me.